# How to Move images from one place to another in a single listbox in a WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, image, listbox

I have Developed a WPF application in which iam adding images to the listbox. Now i want to move the images from one place to another in that listbox. for example - image which is in first position in a listbox has to move some fifth postion my dragging with mouse pointer. 
Any suggestions plz.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This might be of some help. It allows for draging between two lists, but also handles reordering, so it should work.

[Bea Stollnitz: How can I drag and drop items between data bound ItemsControls?](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=53)

Answer (score 0):

You should implement drag and drop for listbox I guess

Comment: may be ur right. but If i move the image from first position to third position 3rd image has to move to 4th position and second image has to move to first postion... In this manner i want drag and drop.